# pickle.dumps(model) TypeError: can’t pickle _thread.RLock objects to fbprophet object on Google App engine

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, facebook-prophet

Trying to store a model trained by using facebook's library **fbprophet** on google app engine flexible and facing this error,

```
pickle.dumps(model) TypeError: can’t pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

on line: pickle.dumps(model)

here is my code

```
client = _get_storage_client()
bucket = client.bucket(settings.GS_BUCKET_NAME)
blob = bucket.blob(path + "/" + filename)
new_file = pickle.dumps(model)
blob.upload_from_string(new_file)
```

I am using python 3.7

Answer (score 0):

Hey @MuhammadUsmanBashir , your issue seems related to the fbprophet library itself. there is an already opened bug for that on github which you can see it [here](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/1361). they suggest downgrading to `fbprophet==0.5` . However, the bug still opened.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Methkal Khalawi. Let me give it shot